# Python Program Correction

Tags: python, macos, terminal, filepath

I need help I am trying to open the terminal and type ifconfig and enter then read the output on a mac then il transition this later to kali but I am getting a error with the file path to terminal and I cant start it, here is my code.

```
import os,sys

#opens terminal

terminal = os.open('/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app', os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND)

#writes ifconfig

os.write(terminal, 'ifconfig')

os.close(terminal)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `subprocess`

```
import subprocess

def popen(executable):
    sb = subprocess.Popen(
        '%s' % executable,
        shell=True,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        universal_newlines=True,
    )
    stdout, stderr = sb.communicate()
    return stdout, stderr, sb.returncode
```

you can pass `ifconfig` to this method and it will execute the command and return the output for you.

Comment: This is an especially good idea, since `Terminal.app` isn't an executable; it is a bundle, which to the filesystem looks like a directory.

Comment: I agree with using subprocess, but that is an outdated and heavy handed example. I would suggest using the new `run` or at least `call` for something this trivial.

Comment: @CasualDemon yeah, you could also use `check_output`

Comment: @AminEtesamian HA, I was actually just writing out that answer and saw your message after I posted it. Agree with check_output is all you need, I  just really like introducing people to the new `run` function, as the new return class is pretty nice.

Comment: @CasualDemon I haven't used it yet. it belongs to `subprocess`?

Comment: @AminEtesamian yup, https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

Comment: I need it so it shows the actuall terminal so the user can select their ip and bssid

Answer (score 1):

I agree with using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). To add to Amin's answer, for something this simple that you just want the output from:

```
import subprocess

print(subprocess.check_output(['ifconfig']))
```

Edit:

What I was talking about in my comment is the new [run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) function that returns a [CompletedProcess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess) class that holds all the relevant information for you. That way you no longer have to have three different variables holding your stdout, sterr and returncode.

Comment: nice thing about the `run`. tnx